# TcpClient подключается даже когда соединения нет

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Не знаю в какую сторону даже копать, может я переработал сильно и что-то упускаю. Вот код.

```
            try
            {
                _client = new TcpClient();
                _client.Connect(IP, 5784);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Func.ShowMessageAsunc(ex.Message);                
                return false;
            }
```

Какой бы IP адрес и порт я не ставил, никогда не выбрасывается исключение. Отключал интернет на компьютере и все равно исключения нет. Приложение запускается на эмуляторе андроид, если там отключить все сети, то исключение появляется.
А сейчас, когда по факту сервис не доступен с которым работает приложение, ошибки нет. Еще пару недель назад все работало. Приложение xamarin forms, framework .NET Standart 2.0.
Подскажите пожалуйста куда смотреть.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94177/discussion-on-question-by-jurzer-tcpclient-----).

Comment: Испробовал множество способов найденных на просторах интернета, но проблему так и не решил. Переустановил систему. (